# How can I do this kind of interface?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have to make a list of elements in a special style like this[image]

I don't even know what to google. Can I do this using ListView?

Comment: Use `gridView` or you can even do that in `listview` also.

Comment: Use `GridView` or `GridLayout`.

Comment: please refer this http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html

Comment: use cardview and tht cardview populate into listview

Answer (score 1):

I usually use recyclerview with GridLayoutManager for that and set span count to 2

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, spanCount);
myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```